# Magento 2 image resize command error images are not same

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.3.4, image-resize

Magento 2.3.4 run image resize command give error images are not same  size domain/pub/media/catalog/product/m/e/megilbert.gif  @ error/layer.c/OptimizeLayerFrames/1023

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue.
I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this error

```
 1953/28251 [>]   6% 42 mins 74.0 MiB   | /4/6/460S-11-PDM-I_1.jpg images are not the same size `/data/media/catalog/product/4/6/460S-11-PDM-SI_1.gif' @ error/layer.c/OptimizeLayerFrames/1023
```

I deleted the */data/media/catalog/product/4/6/460S-11-PDM-SI_1.gif* image and restarted the image generation and it worked for me.